# How does Tensorflow support using optimizers with custom ops?

Tags: tensorflow

I've made a new op and I'd like to use it with AdamOptimizer. I've created a gradient for it following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python) and added it to my optimizer's var_list but Tensorflow says that my variable doesn't have a processor.

Is there support for Tensorflow custom ops in optimizers?
Does the optimizer class let me create a new processor or would I have to rewrite part of compute_gradients?

Also, what does automatic differentiation mean, as stated by the TF docs:

> To make automatic differentiation work for new ops, you must register a gradient function which computes gradients with respect to the ops' inputs given gradients with respect to the ops' outputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean adding a custom op and registering the gradient? The statement just means that we infer the gradient by applying the chain rule. User ops are slightly different from regular ops. A good simple example should be the sigmoid.

Comment: No, I was doing something different. Thanks for the clarification on auto differentiation!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that what I was doing was not supported with Tensorflow optimizer.

I was trying to create an op that would act like a Tensorflow variable (i.e. get updated by the functions within `Optimizer::minimize()`), however, I believe that TF does something weird with processors and `Eigen::Tensors` that I don't fully understand in order to update gradients with `minimize()`, and naturally this doesn't work with Op classes.